# separating grep's output by directory

Tags: bash, split, grep, gawk

Is there any quick way other than manually doing it myself to separate grep's output by the directory/file it came from?

Example of lines/output:

```
  C:/files/yeah1.txt:eaaakkkakaka:eeeaaa
  C:/files/yeah1.txt:iemeirmeiemime:eomeonefneinee
  C:/files/yeah1.txt:eanfienierniene:eoneofneoneo
  C:/files/yeah23.txt:ienfienienein:eingieniene
  C:/files/nowayexample1.txt:49ng49n9n49n393n:g93nm9n39n33
  C:/files/yeadddddddddh1.txt:tg93n93n393n93n3:349n39n39n3
```

So what I want is if output came from `yeah1.txt` go into different output file than `yeah23.txt` and so on.

Comment: I haven't attempted anything as I don't really know what I could do? I'm pretty new to bash overall, i mean I have a thought of using like awk seperate $1 by string, but i don't really know how I'd produce that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F ':' '{n=split($2,a,"/"); print >a[n]}' file
```

This creates four files:

```
yeah23.txt
yeah1.txt
yeadddddddddh1.txt
nowayexample1.txt
```

File yeah1.txt contains, e.g.:

```
C:/files/yeah1.txt:eaaakkkakaka:eeeaaa
C:/files/yeah1.txt:iemeirmeiemime:eomeonefneinee
C:/files/yeah1.txt:eanfienierniene:eoneofneoneo
```

> I explain how it works with this first line:
>
> `C:/files/yeah1.txt:eaaakkkakaka:eeeaaa`

---

> First `awk` splits your line with delimiter `:` in four parts:
>
> `$1`: `C`
>
> `$2`: `/files/yeah1.txt`
>
> `$3`: `eaaakkkakaka`
>
> `$4`: `eeeaaa`

---

> Next, `n=split($2,a,"/")` splits `$2` (`/files/yeah1.txt`) with delimiter `/` in three parts to array `a` and writes number of array elements to variable `n`. Array `a` contains then:
>
> `a[1]`: nothing because there is nothing before first delimiter
>
> `a[2]`: `files`
>
> `a[3]`: `yeah1.txt`
>
> I assumed that the path depth in `$2` can vary and therefore I did not use `a[3]` but `a[n]`. `a[n]` contains always last element of array `a` (here: `yeah1.txt`).

---

> Last step, `print >a[n]` writes the complete line into a file whose name is in last array field (`a[n]`).